# ¿Como puedo saber el valor de un option dentro de un input tipo select en HTML?

Tags: html, jquery, dom

Si tengo este código. ¿Como puedo saber con JQuery o con DOM el valor de, por ejemplo, el option de valor 2?

```
 <select class="select" id="mySelect">
      <option value="0">>HOLA</option>
      <option value="1">>HOLA2</option>
      <option value="2">>HOL3</option>
      <option value="3">>HOLA4</option>
    </select/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

solo tienes que usar:

```
$( "#mySelect" ).val();
```

Si lo que quieres es conseguir la lista de valores puedes usar

```
$("#mySelect").each(function()
{
   $(this).val(); //te retornara el valor
   $(this).text(); // te dará el texto
});
```

Comment: ¿Y una vez que tengo la lista, como saco de ahí los valores?

Comment: Quieres los valores o el texto del option?

Comment: Quiero el texto del option

Comment: Te lo he editado, Un saludo

Comment: Me sale una lista enrome de campos, igual que antes.

Comment: Claro, eso te retorna todos los valores o textos, necesitas añadir un condicional para el que te retorne solo el que te interesa. Al final para que te interesa saber el texto?

Comment: Imagina que hay tres selects con tres options, cada uno tiene asignada por default uno de ellos. Quiero hacer una funcion de tal manera que si uno cambia, el que tenga el mismo valor que el primero cambie su valor al  que el primero tenía antes. Es decir un intercambio de valores. Si 1º tiene A, 2º B y 3ºC y cambio 1ºC quiero que 3ºA. Por eso necesito saber el valor del texto, pero no se como sacarlo, los valores no son solo valores a secas, son un monton de  variables que no entiendo para cada uno de los option.

Comment: y no te sale más a cuenta usar el $( "#mySelect" ).val(); que te retorna el value="0" del option que este seleccionado?

Puedes usar:

<select class="select" id="mySelect2">
      <option value="A">>HOLA</option>
      <option value="B">>HOLA2</option>
      <option value="C">>HOL3</option>
      <option value="D">>HOLA4</option>
    </select/>
<select class="select" id="mySelect">
      <option value="A">>HOLA</option>
      <option value="B">>HOLA2</option>
      <option value="C">>HOL3</option>
      <option value="D">>HOLA4</option>
    </select/>
etc...

Comment: Pues si que me ha servido! Muchas gracias por todo!!

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
let options = document.getElementById("mySelect").
getElementsByTagName("option");
var onemore = 1;
Array.from(options).forEach(e =>{
console.log(`Soy la opción número ${onemore} y tengo de texto:
${e.innerHTML}
`);
onemore++;
});
});
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
 <select class="select" id="mySelect">
      <option value="0">HOLA</option>
      <option value="1">HOLA2</option>
      <option value="2">HOL3</option>
      <option value="3">HOLA4</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```